# Correct way to check for true value without exiting loop in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda, functional-programming, iteration, range

I'm working on a application in Kotlin that needs to iterate over a range, calling a sub-function for each item. The function then returns a boolean indicating if any of the sub-function calls returned true. The problem I'm running into is that the sub-function modifies the state of the data. If I use 'any()' it will exit the loop as soon as one of the sub-function calls returns true. I want to loop over all the items in the range before determining if the result id true or false. I know I could do this by simply storing all the sub-function results in a separate variable, but I feel like there should be a more functional idiomatic way to do this. Is there something similar to 'any()' that will check all items before returning?

For reference, here is a simplified example of my code:

```
var values = mutableListOf(1,2,3)
fun shiftRows(numberOfRows:Int, xRange: IntProgression):Boolean {
    println("shifting row")
    val v1:Boolean = (1..numberOfRows).map { idx -> doSomething( idx, -1  )}.any()
    return v1
}

fun doSomething(index:Int, currentValue:Int):Boolean
{
    //do some row shifting here
    values[index] = currentValue
    return index > 4
}

shiftRows(4, 1..4)
```

Comment: `any` won't make it exit early because you're working with a List, not a Sequence. `IntRange.map` returns a List, not a Sequence. If you were working with a Sequence, you could insert a `toList()` call before `any()` to ensure the entire Sequence is iterated.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [fold()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html):

```kotlin
val v1:Boolean = (1..numberOfRows).fold(false) { acc, idx -> acc or doSomething( idx, -1  ) }
```

It is not as clean as simply `any { }`, but even if speaking English, "any" implies that we don't care about all items, but only about the first we get.

Or we can count matching items:

```kotlin
val v1:Boolean = (1..numberOfRows).count { idx -> doSomething( idx, -1  ) } > 0
```

I suggest creating a properly named extension for this. It is very counter-intuitive that searching for items has side-effects that we expect to happen. However, I see valid uses for the scenario like: "Perform actions on all items and check if any of these actions returned true".